why corewcf wsdl url is difeferent when calling throug reverseproxy
i had an wcfcore service running behind an reverseproxy, when client calls .wsdl it returns localhost address and not reverseproxy address, how to solve this?
i tried to set on AddServiceEndpoint the baseaddress but the error is still there
